# Two ng-click function not executing together

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to execute two functions in one ng-click, but it is not executing.

when I try to execute them individually, it is working fine.

I am separating the two function names using semicolon ' ; '.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic head</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <h4>Enter the details</h4>
    <div class="list list-inset" >
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" name="place" ng-model="data.place" value="" placeholder="Place">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="number" name="pincode" ng-model="data.pincode" value="" placeholder="Pin Code">
      </label>
      <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="savedata(); navigat('/success.html')" >
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the controller code :

```
app.controller('NavCtrl',function($scope,$location,$http,$window){
  $scope.data = {};
  $scope.savedata = function(){
    $http.post("http://localhost/angular/insert2.php",{'place':$scope.data.place,'pincode':$scope.data.pincode})
      .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
    //console.log(data);
        alert("successful");
      })
      .error(function(){
        alert("failed");
      })
  };

  $scope.navigat = function(url){
    $window.location.href=url;
  };

  $scope.submit = function(){
    $scope.savedata();
  //$scope.navigat('/success.html');
 // $window.location.href='/success.html';
  }

});
```

I also tried to call the submit function which calls the other two functions-savedata() and navigat()- but it calls only one function.

I also tried to put these two functions in two different controllers- then call one controller on body element and other on a div element just before button element. But it looks like it is not even loading one controller.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
   app.controller('NavCtrl',function($scope,$location,$http,$window){
  $scope.data = {};
  $scope.savedata = function(){
    $http.post("http://localhost/angular/insert2.php",{'place':$scope.data.place,'pincode':$scope.data.pincode})
      .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
    //console.log(data);
        alert("successful");
        $scope.navigat('/success.html');
      })
      .error(function(){
        alert("failed");
      })
  };

  $scope.navigat = function(url){
    $window.location.href=url;
  };

  $scope.submit = function(){
    $scope.savedata();
  //$scope.navigat('/success.html');
 // $window.location.href='/success.html';
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call navigate inside of `savedata` success.

Because while your `savedata` is being called and waits for ajax response, meanwhile `navigate` is being called and its navigating to new page.

Use call back as follows

```
$scope.savedata = function(callback){
    $http.post("http://localhost/angular/insert2.php",{'place':$scope.data.place,'pincode':$scope.data.pincode})
      .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        alert("successful");
        if(callback) callback($scope);
      })
      .error(function(){
        alert("failed");
      })
  };
```

Call as follows

```
<button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="savedata(function (s) {s.navigat('/success.html')} );" >
        Submit
      </button>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/QF80s7YxsLor70cNxLRk

Comment: Thanks man I gave '$scope.navigat('/success.html'); inside $scope.savedata() .success and just called savedata() from ng-click. Its working now

Comment: If you need to change this navigate URL but your save data is same then you can follow my approach.

Comment: actually, that approach didn't work for me. it is not redirecting to the success page.

Comment: And I needed to use another function getdata with almost similar functionality, which I have done in both methods, but it is not working both ways! it is not redirecting. please help

Comment: You may try $scope.navigate in the callback function

Comment: Edited the solution lightly. You may try this one also.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the navigat('/success.html') inside the success call back of the post call in savedata